# Create a combination on input in Spock test

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

In my Spock test this is my current where block

```
where:
        [A,B,C] << 
        [
            ["A1","B1","C1"],
            ["A1","B1","C2"],
        ]
```

I am trying to simplify this since my input for A and B is always same. I am trying to use combinations() but have been unsuccessful.

I want something like this which does same job as a code above.

```
where:
        [[A,B],[C]] <<                 // incorrect
        [
            [["A1","B1"],["C1","C2"]].combinations()  // incorrect
        ]
```

Currently I get NPE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one solution:

```
where:
[A, B, C] << [[["A1","B1"]],["C1","C2"]].combinations()*.flatten()
```

Comment: Thank Peter, this is what I wanted. 
But is there a way i can say. After this combination , do this 

where:

[A, B, C] << [
[[["A1","B1"]],["C1","C2"]].combinations()*.flatten()],
[[["A1","B1"]],["C3","C4"]].combinations()*.flatten()]
}

More I learn about spock, I am loving it more.
Thanks for creating a great framework.

Comment: Well, you could add the two expressions/collections with `+`, or you could change `["C1","C2"]` to `["C1","C2","C3","C4"]`. Probably time to move the code on the right-hand side of `<<` to a static helper method.

Answer (score 2):

You need something like this:

```
where:
    [A, B, C] << [
        ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'],
        ['b1', 'b3'],
        ['c1']
    ].combinations()
```

You didn't have enough arrays to match your targets, or you tried to incorrectly group your targets into sub-arrays.